# Rails add children records in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that has models: workorders expenses and invoices. For each invoice expense, there is an invexpense record.

The workorders can have children.

When I create an invoice, I want to be able to select expenses from the children to include on the invoice. I'm hoping to create the invexpense records in the invoice model.

The invoice form lists the children expenses in this table:

```
               <% workorder.children.each do |child| %>
                    <% child.expenses.tobill.each do |expense| %>
                        <tr>
                          <td><%= check_box_tag "expense_ids[]", expense.id %></td>
                          <td><%= child.id_desc %></td>
                          <td><%= expense.exp_date %></td>
                          <td><%= expense.description %></td>
                          <td><%= number_to_currency(expense.amount) %></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

If the user checks an expense, then I want to create an invexpense record.

Again - I'm trying to create these records in the invoice model with code like this:

```
 invexpenses.build  linetype_id: 2, expense_id: expense.id
```

But, I don't know how to access the `expense_ids[]`.

Code I've tried:

```
    if self.expense_ids?
    if expense_ids?
    if expense_ids.count > 0
    if params[:expense_ids] ...
```

Is there a way to access the `expense_ids[]` from the invoice form?

I can see them in the request parameters, if the app crashes:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks for your help!

PS - should I be doing this in the controller instead of model?

Comment: Not an answer but Check out [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) its exactly for stuff like this.

Comment: DickieBoy - I will take a look - thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, yes, the params management should go in your controller.
For your form, I've been using simple_form for some time, and it has a specific helper for that.
Here, from their [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) :

The structure would be something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now we have the user form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :company %>
  <%= f.association :roles %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

After that, in your controller, you can access it like this in the `children_params` hash :

```
def children_params
  params.require(:children).permit(:whatever, :another_one, expense_ids: [])
end
```

Please note that theses params are according to what you have now.

If you need anything else, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best answer, but I got it to work by using code in the Invoice controller instead of the model:

```
    newinvexpense = Invexpense.new(
        linetype_id: 2,
        invoice_id: @invoice.id,
        expense_id: params[:expense_ids].first.to_i
    )
```

The above code only works for the first id in the array.  I will update the code to handle all of the ids in the array.